# joining two numpy matrices

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, matrix, numpy, scipy

If you have two numpy matrices, how can you join them together into one? They should be joined horizontally, so that

```
[[0]         [1]               [[0][1]
 [1]     +   [0]         =      [1][0]
 [4]         [1]                [4][1]
 [0]]        [1]]               [0][1]]
```

For example, with these matrices:

```
>>type(X)
>>type(Y)
>>X.shape
>>Y.shape
<class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>
<class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>
(53, 1)
(53, 1)
```

I have tried hstack but get an error:

```
>>Z = hstack([X,Y])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "labels.py", line 85, in <module>
    Z = hstack([X, Y])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py", line 263, in h
stack
    return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py", line 329, in b
mat
    raise ValueError('blocks must have rank 2')
ValueError: blocks must have rank 2
```

Comment: It should work. Oddly enough, your error message refer to sparse matrices while your type(X) says you have matrices and not sparse matrices.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Judging from the traceback, it seems like you've done `from scipy.sparse import *` or something similar, so that `numpy.hstack` is shadowed by `scipy.sparse.hstack`. `numpy.hstack` works fine:

```
>>> X = np.matrix([[0, 1, 4, 0]]).T
>>> Y = np.matrix([[1, 0, 1, 1]]).T
>>> np.hstack([X, Y])
matrix([[0, 1],
        [1, 0],
        [4, 1],
        [0, 1]])
```

Comment: +1 thanks.. ah yes, I was using `scipy.sparse.hstack` instead!

Comment: @Zach: you're welcome. It's a bit unfortunate that `scipy.sparse.hstack` cannot handle dense matrices.

Comment: yes, it's also unfortunate that both scipy and numpy have functions with the same name as when you import both there can be namespace confusion in which method you are calling!