# scipy.sparse.hstack(([1], [2])) -> "ValueError: blocks must be 2-D". Why?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

`scipy.sparse.hstack((1, [2]))` and `scipy.sparse.hstack((1, [2]))` work well, but not `scipy.sparse.hstack(([1], [2]))`. Why is this the case?

Here is a trace of what's happening on my system:

---

```
C:\Anaconda>python
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 28 2015, 16:44:52) [MSC v.
1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> import scipy.sparse
>>> scipy.sparse.hstack((1, [2]))
<1x2 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
        with 2 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
>>> scipy.sparse.hstack((1, 2))
<1x2 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
        with 2 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
>>> scipy.sparse.hstack(([1], [2]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py", line 456, in h
stack
    return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py", line 539, in b
mat
    raise ValueError('blocks must be 2-D')
ValueError: blocks must be 2-D
>>> scipy.version.full_version
'0.16.0'
>>>
```

Comment: I think you mean that `hstack(([1], 2))` works.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks, fixed!

Comment: So did any of us answer your question?

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks for the downvote reminder: both answers are great, I eventually accepted hpaulj's answer as it goes through NumPy implementation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - I didn't downvote you!... but I'm glad both of us helped!  I'm sorry that you did get downvoted though... totally not my fault.

Comment: @rayryeng Whoops wrong assumption, sorry :) Anyway thanks for the information you provided in the answer!

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - You're very welcome.  I actually up-voted your question because it was an interesting one!  The upvote from a long time ago was from me :).  Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coding details are:

```
def hstack(blocks ...):
    return bmat([blocks], ...)

def bmat(blocks, ...):
    blocks = np.asarray(blocks, dtype='object')
    if blocks.ndim != 2:
        raise ValueError('blocks must be 2-D')
    (continue)
```

So trying your alternatives (remembering the extra `[]`):

```
In [392]: np.asarray([(1,2)],dtype=object)
Out[392]: array([[1, 2]], dtype=object)

In [393]: np.asarray([(1,[2])],dtype=object)
Out[393]: array([[1, [2]]], dtype=object)

In [394]: np.asarray([([1],[2])],dtype=object)
Out[394]: 
array([[[1],
        [2]]], dtype=object)

In [395]: _.shape
Out[395]: (1, 2, 1)
```

This last case (your problem case) failed because the result was 3d.

With 2 sparse matrices (expected input):

```
In [402]: np.asarray([[a,a]], dtype=object) 
Out[402]: 
array([[ <1x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 1 stored elements in COOrdinate format>,
        <1x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 1 stored elements in COOrdinate format>]], dtype=object)

In [403]: _.shape
Out[403]: (1, 2)
```

`hstack` is taking advantage of the `bmat` format, by turning a list of matrices into a nested (2d) list of matrices.  `bmat` is meant to be a way of combining a 2d array of sparse matrices into one larger one.  Skipping the step of first making these sparse matrices may, or might not, work.  The code and the documentation don't make any promises.

Answer (score 7):

In the first case of `scipy.sparse.hstack((1, [2]))`, the number 1 is interpreted as a scalar value and the number 2 is interpreted as a dense matrix, and so when you combine these two things together, the data types are coerced so that they are both scalars and you can combine this with `scipy.sparse.hstack` normally.

Here's some more tests to show that this is true with multiple values:

```
In [31]: scipy.sparse.hstack((1,2,[3],[4]))
Out[31]: 
<1x4 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [32]: scipy.sparse.hstack((1,2,[3],[4],5,6))
Out[32]: 
<1x6 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [33]: scipy.sparse.hstack((1,[2],[3],[4],5,[6],7))
Out[33]: 
<1x7 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
```

As you can see, if you have at least one scalar present in `hstack`, this seems to work.

However, when you try to do the second case of `scipy.sparse.hstack(([1],[2]))`, they aren't both scalars anymore and these are both dense matrices, and you can't use `scipy.sparse.hstack` with purely dense matrices.

To reproduce:

```
In [34]: scipy.sparse.hstack(([1],[2]))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-cd79952b2e14> in <module>()
----> 1 scipy.sparse.hstack(([1],[2]))

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.pyc in hstack(blocks, format, dtype)
    451 
    452     """
--> 453     return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
    454 
    455 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.pyc in bmat(blocks, format, dtype)
    531 
    532     if blocks.ndim != 2:
--> 533         raise ValueError('blocks must be 2-D')
    534 
    535     M,N = blocks.shape

ValueError: blocks must be 2-D
```

See this post for more insight: [Scipy error with sparse hstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22872329/scipy-error-with-sparse-hstack)

Therefore, if you want to use this successfully with two matrices, you must make them sparse first, then combine them:

```
In [36]: A = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix([1])

In [37]: B = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix([2])

In [38]: C = scipy.sparse.hstack([A, B])

In [39]: C
Out[39]: 
<1x2 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

---

Interestingly enough, if you tried doing what you did with the dense version of `hstack`, or `numpy.hstack`, then it's perfectly acceptable:

```
In [48]: import numpy as np

In [49]: np.hstack((1, [2]))
Out[49]: array([1, 2])
```

.... things muck up for sparse matrix representations `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.