# Asking a question based on another post regarding Value Error block must be 2-D

Tags: python, scipy

I am new to this site and do not have enough reputation to make comments on the post below so I hope by referring it here, I could get some assistance.

My current input has shape like this:

```
[array([[0.1,0.2], [0.3, 0.4], [0.5, 0.6]])]
```

to this if possible:

```
[[[0.1,0.2], [0.3, 0.4], [0.5, 0.6]]]
```

I received the same error and having the same problem:

```
ValueError: blocks must be 2-D
```

What I wanted to ask based on the solution in the post is that, is there a way do not convert the dense array into coo_matrix. Since converting it will take lots of processes so is there a way to just somehow change it to 2D and then use hstack?

Here is the post:

[scipy.sparse.hstack(([1], [2])) -> "ValueError: blocks must be 2-D". Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900567/scipy-sparse-hstack1-2-valueerror-blocks-must-be-2-d-why/31900729)

Comment: I made some editing.

Comment: `sparse.hstack` is intended for use on `sparse` matrices.  `[1]` is a 1 element list, which can be turned into a 1 element `numpy` array.  `np.hstack` works fine with that.

Comment: True. But somehow since I have others with sparse matrices so I wish not to change it to np.hstack if possible. Do you think there is other way round? thanks again sir

Comment: You should make all inputs to sparse hstack sparse matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You show a list that contains an array:

```
In [370]: alist = [np.array([[0.1,0.2], [0.3, 0.4], [0.5, 0.6]])]
In [371]: alist
Out[371]: 
[array([[0.1, 0.2],
        [0.3, 0.4],
        [0.5, 0.6]])]
```

Just wrapping that in `np.array` produces a 3d array:

```
In [372]: np.array(alist)
Out[372]: 
array([[[0.1, 0.2],
        [0.3, 0.4],
        [0.5, 0.6]]])
```

numpy `hstack` produces a 2d array:

```
In [373]: np.hstack(alist)
Out[373]: 
array([[0.1, 0.2],
       [0.3, 0.4],
       [0.5, 0.6]])
```

That is it takes the 1 element list and joins it to nothing else, returning the element itself.

I don't understand why you got side tracked on to sparse `hstack`.

---

The correct way to use `alist` in sparse hstack:

```
In [386]: sparse.hstack([sparse.coo_matrix(alist[0])])
Out[386]: 
<3x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [387]: _.A
Out[387]: 
array([[0.1, 0.2],
       [0.3, 0.4],
       [0.5, 0.6]])
```

`sparse.coo_matrix(alist)` does not work because, as noted above, making array from it makes a 3d array.  So we have to take it out of the list, `alist[0]`.  Then make a sparse matrix, which can then be passed to `bmat` for further processing.

I think I described in the other SO question, the `sparse.hstack` works by joining the `coo` attributes of the input arrays, making a new `coo` matrix in the process.  So even if we could pass some sort of list or dense array to `hstack`, it will still have to make a `coo` matrix out of each element.

Don't use `sparse.hstack` if you want a faster version of the dense `concatenate`.  Use it if you already have some large sparse matrices, and want to join them, or possibly add a dense column or row.  More than anything it is a convenience tool for building large sparse matrices from smaller pieces.

Comment: Thank you sir. But can I ask whether is it possible to just use sparse.hstack instead? If possible and what is 1 element list mean?